# validating password with salt and sha512whirlpool in mysql

Tags: mysql, hash, salt, sha512, whirlpool

What would the SQL statement be to validate a password if the MySql table that looks like this:

```
user_id   password     salt
-------   --------     ----
 1         23ed2...    m9f3m...
```

I tried:

```
select * from password_table 
where user_id = 1 
and password = shal(`salt` + 'password') 
order by id desc 
limit 1
```

which did not return anything.   The algorithm is sha512 whirlpool.

In php it goes like this:

`hash('sha512', hash('whirlpool', $password));`

It is possible that it can't be done in an sql statement.

Comment: You should never use a simple hash function to protect your user's passwords. You need to use a strong hashing scheme like PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2. Be sure to use a high cost factor/iteration count. It is common to choose the cost so that a single iteration takes at least 100ms. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot securely hash and verify passwords with an SQL-Statement, because salted hashes cannot be searched for, and because most databases do not offer appropriate hash functions.

Instead use a hash function like BCrypt, SCrypt or PBKDF2 from your development language. For verification first search for the hash by username/id only, and afterwards verify the found hash with the development language again.